# Installing Ubuntu with Dual Boot on a 64 Bit Laptop with 4 GB RAM

Tags: dual-boot, 64-bit

I have a Sony Vaio, 64 bit laptop with 4 GB RAM.
Before installing windows, I created portions as 50GB NTFS for Windows 7, 200GB NTFS & rest unpartioned for Ubuntu.
Installed Windows 7, which went through without any trouble.
Next I tried to install Ubuntu, but it is not happening.
While booting the ubuntu instaler DVD is not recognised, same with installer USB. If I check that DVD / USB on any ither system, they are recognised.

What steps should I take to install Ubuntu. I tried 14.04 32 bit and 64 bit.

Comment: How are you booting in UEFI or BIOS legacy mode? Did you try both?

Answer (score 0):

Is it recognized by other system when booting or in fileexplorer?

You have to setup your boot device to USB or DVD.